# Display shortest username and largest username on computer in Linux

Tags: linux

I'm trying to configure a script that displays all the users on the computer, the groups they belong to, and the shortest/longest usernames.

I have the first part set up with the users and groups but I can't figure out the shortest/longest username

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit unclear-- scripting in what language? bash?

If so, the length of a string variable `$FOO` is available as `${#FOO}`. So for example to get the longest user name you could simply do:

```
grep -Eo '^([^:]+)' /etc/passwd | 
while read NAME
do
  echo ${#NAME} ${NAME}
done |
sort -n | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

The `grep` command finds the usernames in the password file (all text from beginning up to first colon).

The `while` loop outputs the lengths of the names along with the names themselves.

`sort -n` sorts the output of the while loop numerically.

`tail -1` takes the last line from the sorted output, which will be the biggest number.

`awk '{print $2}'` prints the second column of the output, which was the name.

The shortest name would be the same except using `head -1` instead of `tail -1`.

Keep in mind that there could well be a tie. There are also lots and lots of other ways you could do this, including using other scripting languages.

Comment: `/etc/passwd` shows only *local* accounts; to see a more complete list, consider using [`getent`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1.html).  Likewise, the existing script could be simplified...